# Scroll pagination on static page

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, pagination

I'm having a news feed page with many tabs(). When I access the page I generate all the HTML, but I don't want to have all the tabs displayed...just the first ones.

How can I make a pagination, similar to Facebook's news feed?

I found [Jscroll](http://jscroll.com/), but there, the pages are individual html pages.

Comment: from the jScroll docs, `the ability to load content via AJAX within the current page or content area as you scroll down`. To my understanding, they don't have to be individual html pages since it's using AJAX to request the next thing to show. From your use-case, it sounds like jScroll is exactly what you need - so I'd take another look

Comment: I don't want to involve any Ajax requests. Lets say that I have 10 <li> but the last ones have display:none. Scrolling, the rest of <li> become visible

Comment: Interesting use - case. But again I bet if you peruse the docs, you can customize what it does when it reaches the "end"/pagination point. Maybe there you can do w/e dom manipulation rather than AJAX.